# EF6 : DbUpdateConcurrencyException : "The database operation was expected to affect X row(s)"

Tags: c#, ef-core-6.0

**The minimal project sources to reproduce the issue is here :**

https://wetransfer.com/downloads/8d9325ce7117bb362bf0d61fc7c8571a20220708100401/326add

===================

This error is a classic; In layman's terms it is usually caused by a "bad" insertion when a navigation is not properly taken in account, causing a faulty Ef state somewhere.

Many solutions have been posted along the years but I fail to see how my specific scenario could cause the issue!

**My schema is a many-to-many between Groups and Users.** The middle entity is named GroupUser.

**There's a twist : Each GroupUser has an owned entity containing extra data, DataPayload.** This choice was made for versatility -- we wanted that payload to be stored in its own table.

Schema:

```
public class User {

    public Guid Id { get; private set; }

    public IList<GroupUser> GroupUsers { get; private set; } = new List<GroupUser>();

    public User(Guid id) { Id = id; }

}


public class Group {

    public Guid Id { get; private set; }

    public Group(Guid id) { Id = id; }
}




public class GroupUser {

    public Guid Id { get; private set; }

    public Guid GroupId { get; private set; }

    public Guid UserId { get; private set; }

    // Navigation link
    public Group? Group { get; private set; }



    public DataPayload? Data { get; private set; }


    public GroupUser(Guid groupId, Guid userId, DataPayload data) {
        Id = Guid.NewGuid(); //Auto generated
        UserId = userId;
        GroupId = groupId;
        Data = data;
    }

    // This extra constructor is only there to make EF happy! We do not use it.
    public GroupUser(Guid id, Guid groupId, Guid userId) {
        Id = id;
        UserId = userId;
        GroupId = groupId;
    }
}



public class DataPayload {
    //Note how we did not defined an explicit Id; we let EF do it as part of the "Owned entity" mechanism.

    ///// <summary>foreign Key to the Owner</summary>
    public Guid GroupUserId { get; private set; }

    public int DataValue { get; private set; }


    public DataPayload(int dataValue) {
        DataValue = dataValue;
    }


    public void SetDataValue(int dataValue) {
        DataValue = dataValue;
    }
}
```

To make it all work, we configure the navigations like this :

```
//  ---------  Users  ---------

builder
    .ToTable("Users")
    .HasKey(u => u.Id);


//  ---------  Groups  ---------

builder
    .ToTable("Groups")
    .HasKey(g => g.Id);


//  ---------  GroupUsers  ---------

builder
    .ToTable("GroupUsers")
    .HasKey(gu => gu.Id);

builder
    .HasOne<User>() //No navigation needed
    .WithMany(u => u.GroupUsers)
    .HasForeignKey(gu => gu.UserId);

builder
    .HasOne<Group>(gu => gu.Group) //Here, we did define a navigation
    .WithMany()
    .HasForeignKey(gu => gu.GroupId);

builder
    .OwnsOne(gu => gu.Data,
        navBuilder => {
            navBuilder.ToTable("PayloadDatas");

            navBuilder.Property<Guid>("Id"); //Note: Without this EF would try to use 'int'
            navBuilder.HasKey("Id");

            //Configure an explicit foreign key to the owner. It will make our life easier in our Unit Tests
            navBuilder.WithOwner().HasForeignKey(d => d.GroupUserId);
        }
    );
//.OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade) // Not needed (default behaviour for an owned entity)
```

Now, you know how everything is defined.

**Basic setup : works!**

```
var group = new Group(groupId);
await dbContext.Groups.AddAsync(group);
await dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();

var user = new User(userId);
await dbContext.Users.AddAsync(user);
await dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
```

**Follow-up scenario : fails!**

```
var groupUser = new GroupUser(groupId, userId, new DataPayload(dataValue: 777777));
user.GroupUsers.Add(groupUser);
await dbContext.SaveChangesAsync(); // Crash happens here!!!
```

Error:

```
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateConcurrencyException : The database operation was expected to affect 1 row(s), but actually affected 0 row(s); data may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded.
```

I suspect that EF gets confused by the addition of **two** entities at once, where it has to compute some Ids itself : the new GroupUser **and** the DataPayload it contains. I'm not sure how it's supposed to know that it needs to give an Id to the GroupUser first and then use that Id as the foreign key in PayloadData. But that's just me; it might or might not be related to the issue.

But what do I need to change?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include your source code as a working [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others.

Comment: done - see link at the beginning of the post

Comment: Please add your code to the question itself, not on an external site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mistake was in GroupUser's id-less constructor:

Id = **Guid.NewGuid();**

The code needs to **let EF manage the keys** when it comes to owned entities such as DataPayload which rely on a foreign key (GroupUserId) that's **still in the making** at the time of saving.

If you set a key value (Guid.NewGuid()) yourself, then EF gets confused between:

- linking the new DataPayload entity to the GroupUser entity where you've shoehorned an Id value,

OR

- just expecting an empty value (foreign key) and setting all the keys (both the GroupUser's Id and DataPayload's GroupUserId) itself.

All in all, EF feels like you announced that you were about to let it create 1 entity, but you've pulled the rug under its feet and done it yourself, so it ends up with 0  entity to work with. Hence the error message.

It should have been :

Id = **Guid.Empty;**

With Guid.Empty, EF clearly identifies that this entity is **new** and that has to be the **same one** as the one you told it to create and link to the new PayloadData -- that is, the instance that you've set in GroupUser.Data.